# Date Formatting in Objective C (iOS SDK)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsdateformatter

Hope you can help. I am importing the current GMT time for an iPhone App. This is being retrieved via a JSON web service.

I believe I have the correct formatter string however I am getting a different date (time is still correct) when I try to format the date I've retrieved. The JSON date is formatted like this: Sun, 15 May 2011 20:35:31 +0000

In the example below strGMT is the date in the format I've just mentioned.

This is the code I'm using to get retrieved date into my code:

```
NSLog(@"Current GMT: %@", strGMT);
NSDateFormatter *gmtFormatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[gmtFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss VVVV"];
//THIS IS NOT REFORMATTING CORRECTLY HERE
NSDate *gmtDateTime=[gmtFormatter dateFromString:strGMT];
NSLog(@"Current Formatted GMT Date: %@", gmtDateTime);
```

The log is showing the following:

Current GMT: Sun, 15 May 2011 20:35:31 +0000

Current Formatted GMT Date: 2010-12-26 20:35:31 +0000

Have I not got the formatting string correct? Any ideas why it's gone from 15 May 2011 (today) to 26th December 2010?

Kind regards

Paul

Comment: This might help figure it out [Date Field Symbol Table](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date%5FFormat%5FPatterns)

Comment: see this link it is also helpful: http://tugdualgrall.blogspot.in/2011/01/ios-101-how-to-convert-string-to-nsdate.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct format string is `@"EEE, dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss VVVV"`